# data.table column assignments as a stored function

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table in an R package that I'm writing which is very large. To keep the size down for distribution, I'm eliminating all columns from the table that can be calculated from other columns. For example, day of week can be calculated from the date, so I leave out day of week from the package data set. However, I want to make it convenient to recalculate these columns in a standard way for anyone that uses the package. I'd like to do it with the `data.table` in place assignments, for the sake of efficiency. I'm imagining something like this:

```
dt = myPackageData  # minimal data set included in the package
extend_dow = function(your_data_table) {
  your_data_table[,`:=`(day_of_week = lubridate::wday(my_date))]
}
extend_dow(dt)
```

And then `dt` would have the `day_of_week` column available for use.

The problem that I'm running into is that the in-place assignment of the new column seems to be occurring in a lower level environment, and the data.table that I pass to the function doesn't actually get modified.

Does anyone know how I can store the complete formula for a new column, which can be applied using a single function call to the same data.table that the user passes to the function?

Comment: The approach works with a data.table I create manually. Please confirm that it does for you too and that it only doesn't with a data.table created using `dataset`. PS: It should be `your_data_table[...` inside the function.

Comment: Where/how is `dataset` defined?

Comment: Note also that base R has a `weekdays` function that will do this as well: `weekdays(as.Date("2010-01-01"))`.

Comment: @Roland I updated the question because I referenced the wrong data.table in the function. Take a look again. As for how the table is packaged, it's included in the package as a data.table. however, you can't modify a package data set in a session, so the user needs to first make a copy. Accordingly, the formula needs to take the copied table as an argument and modify it in place.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The example that I posted above *does* work, but only if you make a `data.table::copy` of the `data.table` before feeding it to the function, like so:

```
library(myPackage)
library(data.table)
dt = copy(myPackageData)
extend.weekday = function(your_data_table) {
  your_data_table[,`:=`(day_of_week = lubridate::wday(my_date))]
}
extend.weekday(dt)
```

The mistake in my example is that I was assigning the package data directly to `dt = myPackageData`, without making a `copy`. In that case, the column extension does not get applied. I would guess that this is because the object is still referencing the package data somehow, which prevents any changes from being applied when the function is executed.